# NSUrlConnectionDelegate - Getting http status codes

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, http-response-codes, nsurlconnectiondelegate

in iOS, how can I receive the http status code (404,500 200 etc) for a response from a web server. I am assuming it's in the NSUrlConnectionDelegate.

Objective-C or **Monotouch** .NET answer ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938010/how-do-i-check-an-http-request-response-status-code-from-ios.

Comment: Edited question to request Monotouch

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes, you can get status code in delegate method -didRecieveResponse:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
   NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
   int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
}
```

Comment: Note that, despite the use of dot notation, statusCode is not a property.

Comment: @albertamg, oops indeed... thanks, will correct that to avoid confusion

Comment: I realise this is obvious, but I'll note it just for the sake of completeness: anywhere else that you get an `NSURLResponse` in response to a HTTP request (such as the completion handler of `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`, you can cast the `NSURLResponse` to an `NSHTTPURLResponse` in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 11):

```
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```

The aSynchronous request should also have a way to get the NSHTTPURLResponse..

You get the status code like this:

```
int statusCode = [urlResponse statusCode];
int errorCode = error.code;
```

In the case of some much used error codes (like 404) it will get put in the error but with a different code (401 will be -1012).

Comment: There is no need to alloc error - just check if error is not null on return - if it isn't you should have an error code

Comment: Thanks heaps, that helped me.  Thanks for the 401, that the error I was trying to trap. error.code = -1012 as you said.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it in MonoTouch for .NET for those C# users. THis is in the **NSUrlConnectionDelegate**.

```
public override void ReceivedResponse (NSUrlConnection connection, NSUrlResponse response)
{
  if (response is NSHttpUrlResponse)
  {
    var r = response as NSHttpUrlResponse;
    Console.WriteLine (r.StatusCode);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325362/nsurl-error-handling) it looks like you can handle http status codes in the `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` delegate method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response 
{
    if ([response isKindOfClass: [NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
        statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*) response statusCode];
}
```