# iOS App to test HTTP Response codes and time

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I am creating an iOS app in which I want to test several servers with a HTTP request. The app needs to look at a plist file with all the servers to test and expected end results, then execute the test and return a response code (i.e.: 200, 404, etc)

This information needs to then be saved to a server for later evaluation.

The problem I am having is I am unable to find a good viable way to just test a server. I don't need to download anything or save any content from the server, just test it.

How might some of you go about this? AFNetworking? Reachability? NSURLConnection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSURLConnection` to issue a simple `GET` request to the server (i.e, http://www.google.com) and check the response code. You have several delegate methods, for successful and failed request.

This can be done using this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/6918832/975959

Issuing a `GET` request is pretty simple with `NSURLConnection`. for example, see [here](http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try using NSURLConnection. Any chance you know a good resource to do this with AFNetworking?

Comment: I've never used AFNetworking myself, only ASIHTTPRequest, but a quick Google lead to this: http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/ which looks like a good place to start.
Also, If you think this is the correct answer, please accept it.
Good luck

Comment: Gave AFNetworking a shot and NSURLConneciton a shot. Both seem to do what I want to do. Querying things is a bit tough but both are viable solutions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Reachability checks if the network is reachable or not, it won't get any status codes back. Probably not what you want.

Instead, you probably want to make `HEAD` requests. They're basically the same thing as `GET`, only, without a response body. You can use `NSURLConnection` for this, or `AFNetworking` (which is a wrapper on top of `NSURLConnection`).